# How can I scroll to the selected option after page refresh?

Tags: angular

I have searched the internet, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

**What I am doing:**

I have a ng-select that do infinite scrolling.

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selected" id="studentsSelect" bindLabel="nameSelect" class="custom" (scrollToEnd)="fetchMore($event)">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let student of infinite" [value]="student">{{student.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

So the array `infinite` gets populated when a user scroll to the bottom of the dropdown. When the page reloads it fetch from the `students` array and insert into the `infinite` array + 10 entries (if it can), so that it can select the saved option and be viewed in the dropdown list.

Also I save the state of the dropdown. So if you go to another location and back it will keep the selected option and repeat the top paragraph.

When the user returns to this page, the selected get set. But when you open the dropdown list, it doesn't scroll to the selected option. But if you close the dropdown and open it again without doing anything else, then it scrolled to it.

I'm not sure what is happening, or if there is something that I need to set.

Also no jquery may be used.

Comment: you could put it on top.

Comment: i think you are mixing angular 1 and angular 6 syntax

Comment: Sound like you want some event to trigger that doesn't trigger restoring the state.

Comment: @firegloves Yeah, I'm super new to angular.

Comment: @itdoesntwork that is a cool idea

Comment: @MarkBaijens, yeah feels like after you clicked the drop down, an event gets fired, doing the scroll thing, but doesn't update the view immediately or something

Comment: @itdoesntwork idea was rejected...

Comment: @JBin, I don't know angular so well, so someone might know a better solution, but you could try to trigger "scrollToEnd" manually on page load.

Comment: checkout both the links you may get some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354465/persisting-scroll-position-in-angular-after-refresh and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position, this is just to keep the scroll position on page refresh